# How to update data in Qdrant using langchain.js?

Tags: javascript, langchain, vector-database, qdrant

I am using langchain.js [`QdrantVectorStore`](https://js.langchain.com/docs/integrations/vectorstores/qdrant) to perform CRUD operations in Qdrant collection. I see that there are many options available in js `QdrantVectorStore` to add data to Qdrant but I don't see any method to update points in a cluster using langchain.js.
I know I can use [Qdrant js sdk](https://github.com/qdrant/qdrant-js) to perform Updates to points but I prefer doing it using `QdrantVectorStore` for the following reasons:

1. it simply takes the text and Embedding model and do the rest. we don't have to manually convert text to embeddings or vectors.
2. Qdrant has different APIs to update [vectors](https://qdrant.tech/documentation/concepts/points/) and [payload](https://qdrant.tech/documentation/concepts/payload/#update-payload), Since `QdrantVectorStore` stores the actual text in `payload.content` along with the vectors so using qdrant sdk I will have to perfrom the vector and payload updates seperately with two API calls.

Although using Qdrant vector stores allows writing a clean code.

This [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/LangChain/comments/17bc1ij/update_collection_in_qdrantdont_want_to_create/) suggests using `add_documents` even for update but that suggestion is for langchain.py not for js. But I tried something similar in langchain.js, I tried to use `QdrantVectorStore.addDocuments()` to update data but I couldn't find a way to pass `pointId[]` to specify which point to update.
I also checked the types and interfaces for `QdrantVectorStore.addDocuments()` so I found this

```
type QdrantAddDocumentOptions = {
    customPayload: Record<string, any>[];
};
addDocuments(documents: Document[], documentOptions?: QdrantAddDocumentOptions): Promise<void>;
```

As a last resort I also tried passing an array of pointIds in `customPayload` but that didn't work. it was simply creating a point in cluster with the ids I passed in `customPayload`.